# How to integrate EIP-2981 with this basic ERC-721 contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm looking to integrate these two things together into one contract for a basic 1/1 NFT. How exactly is this written together? Note they are two different compilers and they both need to be the same I think. I'm working within remix IDE if it helps to know.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.6;

import "https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token-metadata.sol";
import "https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/ownership/ownable.sol";

contract newNFT is NFTokenMetadata, Ownable {

  constructor() {
    nftName = "Synth NFT";
    nftSymbol = "SYN";
  }

  function mint(address _to, uint256 _tokenId, string calldata _uri) external onlyOwner {
    super._mint(_to, _tokenId);
    super._setTokenUri(_tokenId, _uri);
  }

}
```

and

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

interface IERC2981 {

    /// @notice Called with the sale price to determine how much royalty
    //          is owed and to whom.
    /// @param _tokenId - the NFT asset queried for royalty information
    /// @param _salePrice - the sale price of the NFT asset specified by _tokenId
    /// @return receiver - address of who should be sent the royalty payment
    /// @return royaltyAmount - the royalty payment amount for _salePrice
    function royaltyInfo(
        uint256 _tokenId,
        uint256 _salePrice
    ) external view returns (
        address receiver,
        uint256 royaltyAmount
    );
}
```

https://medium.com/geekculture/mint-an-nft-and-erc-721-smart-contract-easy-step-by-step-4fafff151fbe

https://medium.com/knownorigin/eip-2981-simple-and-effective-royalty-standards-for-all-dbd0b761a0f0

Answer (score 3):

check out https://www.gemini.com/blog/exploring-the-nft-royalty-standard-eip-2981 for an article.  They are using the openzepplin contracts vs. 0xcert

the solidity code is on https://github.com/dievardump/EIP2981-implementation

This is rough but I threw it together and did a couple transactions in Remix and it seemed to work - I'm still a beginner with this so if you see any big problems please let me know...:

The mock contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.6;

//this was created from https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/blob/master/src/contracts/mocks/nf-token-metadata-enumerable-mock.sol
//and royalty was from here https://www.gemini.com/blog/exploring-the-nft-royalty-standard-eip-2981 and https://github.com/dievardump/EIP2981-implementation

import "https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/blob/master/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token-metadata.sol";
import "https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/blob/master/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token-enumerable.sol";
import "https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/blob/master/src/contracts/ownership/ownable.sol";

import './ERC2981PerTokenRoyalties.sol';

  //These are the most common errors I experienced as I set it up:
  //18001 Not current owner of contract
  //18002 can not transfer to zero address
  //string constant ZERO_ADDRESS = "003001";
  //string constant NOT_VALID_NFT = "003002";
  //string constant NOT_OWNER_OR_OPERATOR = "003003";
  //string constant NOT_OWNER_APPROVED_OR_OPERATOR = "003004";
  //string constant NOT_ABLE_TO_RECEIVE_NFT = "003005";
  //string constant NFT_ALREADY_EXISTS = "003006";
  //string constant NOT_OWNER = "003007";
  //string constant IS_OWNER = "003008";

/**
 * @dev This is an example contract implementation of NFToken with enumerable and metadata
 * extensions.
 */
contract XXXXXXXXXXX is
  NFTokenEnumerable,
  NFTokenMetadata,
  Ownable,
  ERC2981PerTokenRoyalties
{

  /**
   * @dev Contract constructor.
   * @param _name A descriptive name for a collection of NFTs.
   * @param _symbol An abbreviated name for NFTokens.
   */
    constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol
  )
  {
    nftName = _name;
    nftSymbol = _symbol;
  }


  /**
   * @dev Mints a new NFT.
   * @param _to The address that will own the minted NFT.
   * @param _tokenId of the NFT to be minted by the msg.sender.
   * @param _uri String representing RFC 3986 URI.
   */
  function mint(
    address _to,
    uint256 _tokenId,
    string calldata _uri,
    address royaltyRecipient,
    uint256 royaltyValue
  )
    external
    onlyOwner
  {
    super._mint(_to, _tokenId);
    super._setTokenUri(_tokenId, _uri);
    
    if (royaltyValue > 0) {
        _setTokenRoyalty(_tokenId, royaltyRecipient, royaltyValue);
    }
    
  }

  /**
   * @dev Removes a NFT from owner.
   * @param _tokenId Which NFT we want to remove.
   */
  function burn(
    uint256 _tokenId
  )
    external
    onlyOwner
  {
    super._burn(_tokenId);
  }


  function setTokenUriX(
    uint256 _tokenId,
    string calldata _uri
  )
    external
    onlyOwner
  {
    super._setTokenUri(_tokenId, _uri);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Mints a new NFT.
   * @notice This is an internal function which should be called from user-implemented external
   * mint function. Its purpose is to show and properly initialize data structures when using this
   * implementation.
   * @param _to The address that will own the minted NFT.
   * @param _tokenId of the NFT to be minted by the msg.sender.
   */
  function _mint(
    address _to,
    uint256 _tokenId
  )
    internal
    override(NFToken, NFTokenEnumerable)
    virtual
  {
    NFTokenEnumerable._mint(_to, _tokenId);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Burns a NFT.
   * @notice This is an internal function which should be called from user-implemented external
   * burn function. Its purpose is to show and properly initialize data structures when using this
   * implementation. Also, note that this burn implementation allows the minter to re-mint a burned
   * NFT.
   * @param _tokenId ID of the NFT to be burned.
   */
  function _burn(
    uint256 _tokenId
  )
    internal
    override(NFTokenMetadata, NFTokenEnumerable)
    virtual
  {
    NFTokenEnumerable._burn(_tokenId);
    if (bytes(idToUri[_tokenId]).length != 0)
    {
      delete idToUri[_tokenId];
    }
  }

  /**
   * @dev Removes a NFT from an address.
   * @notice Use and override this function with caution. Wrong usage can have serious consequences.
   * @param _from Address from wich we want to remove the NFT.
   * @param _tokenId Which NFT we want to remove.
   */
  function _removeNFToken(
    address _from,
    uint256 _tokenId
  )
    internal
    override(NFToken, NFTokenEnumerable)
  {
    NFTokenEnumerable._removeNFToken(_from, _tokenId);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Assignes a new NFT to an address.
   * @notice Use and override this function with caution. Wrong usage can have serious consequences.
   * @param _to Address to wich we want to add the NFT.
   * @param _tokenId Which NFT we want to add.
   */
  function _addNFToken(
    address _to,
    uint256 _tokenId
  )
    internal
    override(NFToken, NFTokenEnumerable)
  {
    NFTokenEnumerable._addNFToken(_to, _tokenId);
  }

   /**
   * @dev Helper function that gets NFT count of owner. This is needed for overriding in enumerable
   * extension to remove double storage(gas optimization) of owner nft count.
   * @param _owner Address for whom to query the count.
   * @return Number of _owner NFTs.
   */
  function _getOwnerNFTCount(
    address _owner
  )
    internal
    override(NFToken, NFTokenEnumerable)
    view
    returns (uint256)
  {
    return NFTokenEnumerable._getOwnerNFTCount(_owner);
  }

}
```

ERC2981PerTokenRoyalties.sol contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

import 'https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/blob/master/src/contracts/utils/erc165.sol';

import './IERC2981Royalties.sol';

/// @dev This is a contract used to add ERC2981 support to ERC721 and 1155
abstract contract ERC2981PerTokenRoyalties is ERC165, IERC2981Royalties {
    struct Royalty {
        address recipient;
        uint256 value;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Royalty) internal _royalties;


    /// @dev Sets token royalties
    /// @param id the token id fir which we register the royalties
    /// @param recipient recipient of the royalties
    /// @param value percentage (using 2 decimals - 10000 = 100, 0 = 0)
    function _setTokenRoyalty(
        uint256 id,
        address recipient,
        uint256 value
    ) internal {
        require(value <= 10000, 'ERC2981Royalties: Too high');

        _royalties[id] = Royalty(recipient, value);
    }

    /// @inheritdoc IERC2981Royalties
    function royaltyInfo(uint256 tokenId, uint256 value)
        external
        view
        override
        returns (address receiver, uint256 royaltyAmount)
    {
        Royalty memory royalty = _royalties[tokenId];
        return (royalty.recipient, (value * royalty.value) / 10000);
    }
}
```

IERC2981Royalties contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

/// @title IERC2981Royalties
/// @dev Interface for the ERC2981 - Token Royalty standard
interface IERC2981Royalties {
    /// @notice Called with the sale price to determine how much royalty
    //          is owed and to whom.
    /// @param _tokenId - the NFT asset queried for royalty information
    /// @param _value - the sale price of the NFT asset specified by _tokenId
    /// @return _receiver - address of who should be sent the royalty payment
    /// @return _royaltyAmount - the royalty payment amount for value sale price
    function royaltyInfo(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _value)
        external
        view
        returns (address _receiver, uint256 _royaltyAmount);
}
```

The above is using 0xcert base contracts... I just saw [this code](https://github.com/Maxflowo2/ERC2981) that leverages openzepplin --it looks very well written.

Answer (score 1):

[This repo](https://github.com/alxrnz2/ERC1155-with-EIP2981-for-OpenSea#eip-2981-royalties) has an ERC 1155 implementation with EIP 2981 royalties; for an ERC 721, you'd just need to import IERC2981 and then add the royaltyInfo function and supportsInterface override to the token contract.